# Has anyone seen .NET 4 RC MVC2 RTM web apps hogging CPU on Win2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net-mvc

We have a number of .NET4 RC ASP.NET MVC2 RTM web applications running on a Windows 2008 R2 server. All behave very well except one that we regularly find running at 99% CPU.

It is the most complex of the applications, but is not doing anything extraordinary. It relies on ASP.NET Cache quite heavily, but we have limited the amount of memory it is allowed to use.

Does this sound like an issue with the environment?

Rich

Comment: I have set CPU limits on the Application Pool with a Kill action. Will monitor event log over the next couple of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a lame answer, but the .NET 4 RTM seemed to resolve these issues.

Answer (score 1):

What does a profiler say where the CPU time sis spent?

Comment: I hadn't been tracking CPU time on the last occurrence, but will do for next time.